# Navigation back button returning to a view controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

As you can see in the images below. I have Manuals tab that shows an overview of manuals. Once I open click on a manual, if it has a structure it will be opened in a table view controller containing different structures. When going to a one of the structures it will open them in a Document View Controller. Now this document view controller has a back button that should specify to go back to the structure if a manual has a structure. Current the document view controller has a button that takes me back to the open documents (the documents that are open)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your `structure` view controller is not included in the UINavigationController. My recommendation would be to set up the three views in a navigation controller. When someone selects a manual, go the the structure page regardless of whether there are one or many. From there they can select a structure to go onto the actual manual page.